# Remove every html tag with JsHtmlSanitizer

Tags: javascript

I finnally got the [JsHtmlSanitizer](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer) working as a standalone clientside script.
Now I'd like to remove all HTML-Tags from a string and not just script-tags and links.
This example

```
html_sanitize('<b>hello</b><img src="http://google.com"><a href="javascript:alert(0)"><script src="http://www.google.com"><\/script>');
```

returns "**hello**" but I'd like to remove all tags.

Comment: At that point, why not just treat it as an XML document and get the innerText?

Comment: I want to implement a live-preview with bb-code in a programm I'm currently working on. So first I want to remove all HTML-Tags and then convert the BB-Code to HTML

Comment: So why not just treat it as an XML document and get the innerText?

Comment: Sorry, I dont get your point

Comment: @JohnDoe: Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/UeVgA/3/. You can convert input string to Document. And traverse it to get text nodes or whatever you like.

Comment: What output do you expect to see?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko why not just use frag.innerText after you add html to sandbox instead of parse dom tree?

Comment: @anton_byrna: I've copied `getText` from sizzle (there is a note about it). `// innerText usage removed for consistency of new lines (see #11153)` http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11153

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use regular expressions to remove all HTML tags after sanitizing?

```
var input = '<b>hello</b><img src="http://google.com"><a href="javascript:alert(0)"><script src="http://www.google.com"></script>';
var output = null;
output = html_sanitize(input);
output = output.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');
```

This should strip your input string of *all* html tags after sanitization.

If you want to do just basic sanitization (removing script and style tags with their content and all html tags only) you could implement the entire thing within regex. I have demonstrated an example below.

```
var input = '<b>hello</b><img src="http://google.com"><a href="javascript:alert(0)"><script src="http://www.google.com"></script>';
input += '<script> if (1 < 2) { alert("This script should be removed!"); } </script><style type="text/css">.cssSelectorShouldBeRemoved > .includingThis { background-color: #FF0000; } </style>';

var output = null;
output = input.replace(/(?:<(?:script|style)[^>]*>[\s\S]+?<\/(?:script|style)[^>]*>)|<[^>]+>/ig, '');
```

Comment: Don't you know that there's a bot that crawls SO for answers containing "regular expressions" and "HTML", and auto-posts this link as a comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript function below to remove all html tags from the string you get from **html_sanitize()**.

```
var output = html_sanitize('<b>hello</b><img src="http://google.com"><a href="javascript:alert(0)"><script src="http://www.google.com"><\/script>');

output = output.replace(/(<.*?>)/ig,"");
```

Hope it helps :)